# Conditional redirection in JSF

Tags: jsf, redirect

is there a build-in mechanism to conditionally redirect to another view? I want the user to be redirected from the login page to the "home page" if he/she is already logged in.

I already have two basic approaches, but for the first I have no idea how to achieve and the second is sort of a dirty workaround.

1. Add `<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=home.jsf" />` and let it be rendered conditionally (EL : `#{login.loggedIn}`)
2. Add a `<h:panelGroup />` which will also be conditionally rendered, containing some JavaScript doing the redirect.

Is there a way to achieve *1* or even another, more elegant solution? :-)

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use [`<f:event type="preRenderView">`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/event.html) for this.

E.g.

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{login.checkAlreadyLoggedin}" />
```

with

```
public void checkAlreadyLoggedin() throws IOException {
    if (isLoggedIn()) {
        ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        ec.redirect(ec.getRequestContextPath() + "/home.xhtml");
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Works like a charme, thanks. In the meantime I discovered and tried another approach: I implemented a filter that was exclusively registered for the log in page, but it failed as I could not manage to access the `@SessionScoped` `login` bean nor the `User` it manages. The session was empty...?!

Comment: The filter will only work for a JSF `@ManagedBean`, not for a CDI `@Named` bean.

Comment: Why doesn't returning a String from the listener method of the `preRenderView` event like `return "home.xhtml?faces-redirect=true"` work (doesn't make a redirect)?

Comment: @Tiny: because it's a listener method not an action method. Essentially, the listener method is being abused here. That's why JSF guys introduced `<f:viewAction>` in JSF 2.2, which should be the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

The solution set out by @BalusC doesn't work in case the view 'home.xhtml' is not the default view of the JSF portlet. For those who need to redirect to a non-default view during the render phase, I suggest the solution set out within [this entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878828/liferay-portlet-and-jsf-redirect-during-render-phase?rq=1). That is, within the `preRenderView` method do the following:

```
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
NavigationHandler navigationHandler = fc.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
navigationHandler.handleNavigation(fc, null, "/views/nonDefaultView.xhtml?faces-redirect=true");
fc.renderResponse();
```

Credits to [@Frizz1977](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1794049/frizz1977)