# Redirect to page using JSF PhaseListener

Tags: jsf-2, liferay-6

Scenario 1:
If the friendlyURL is '/requestform/servicerequest' and `requestProcessorBean.userRequestVO == null` then invalidate the session and redirect to '/web/pds/login' page..

Scenario 2:
If the If the friendlyURL is '/requestform/servicerequest' and `requestProcessorBean.userRequestVO != null` then redirect to 'serviceRequest.xhtml' page.

I want to know how I can Scenario 1 implement using JSF Phase Listener. I have implemented Scenario 1 as follows:
**requestForm.xhtml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<f:view xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:outputFormat rendered="#{lookupBean.friendlyURL == '/requestform/servicerequest' and (requestProcessorBean.userRequestVO != null)}">
            <ui:include src="serviceRequest.xhtml" />
        </h:outputFormat>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
```

I am using Liferay 6.0 and JSF 2.0.

Thanks

Comment: Are you positive what you want is redirection? What you're doing right now is a dynamic include, not a redirect (which actually results in the user being taken to another view). Please specify what you really need

Comment: I want to do a redirect for Scenario 1 I want to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I really won't recommend a phase listener for the conditional redirect. Use instead, the [`<f:event type="preRenderView"/>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8399591/1530938). If however, for some reason you're constrained to use a phaselistener, your implementation would look like this:

1. Define a PhaseListener to look like this

   ```
   /*we're defining the PhaseListener as a ManagedBean so
    * we can inject other beans into it 
    */
   @ManagedBean(name = "thePhaseListener")
   @RequestScoped
   public class TestPhaseListener implements PhaseListener {


      @ManagedProperty(value = "#{requestProcessorBean}")
      transient private RequestProcessorBean requestProcessorBean;

      @ManagedProperty(value = "#{lookupBean}")
      transient private LookupBean lookupBean;

      @Override
      public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
         //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
      }

      @Override
      public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {

          try {

             if (lookupBean.getFriendlyURL.equals("/requestform/servicerequest") && (requestProcessorBean.getUserRequestVO() == null)) {
               event.getFacesContext().getExternalContext().redirect("/web/pds/login");
              }
           } catch (IOException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(TestPhaseListener.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           }
        }

      @Override
      public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
         return PhaseId.RESTORE_VIEW; // The RESTORE_VIEW phase is the first in the lifecycle of a JSF view
      }
   }
   ```
2. Register your new PhaseListener with the tag below on the page you desire

   ```
   <f:phaseListener type="com.you.TestPhaseListener"/>
   ```

Like I mentioned at the beginning of this post, this approach is unnecessarily clunky, too much effort to achieve so little and IMO, an abuse of phaselisteners.